# In Oracle, how do I select rows which contain a character within a certain numeric range?

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a table in Oracle with a VARCHAR column called DESCRIPTION. Some of the rows contain non-printable characters such as the character with numeric value 150 (which is not in Latin-1 and is "Start of Protected Area" in Unicode).

I want to select all the rows whose DESCRIPTION columns contain a character whose numeric value is between 128 and 160. Is there a way to do this without a long list of LIKE clauses OR'ed together? I suppose it can be done with regular expressions, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to do something very like this recently and used some SQL like this:

```
with codes as (select rownum code from dual connect by level <= 160)
select distinct t.id, t.description
from mytable t, codes c
where t.description like '%' || chr(c.code) || '%'
and c.code >= 128;
```

Answer (score 1):

Vincent's post helped me a lot with this problem!  I wanted to find all rows that had any extended ASCII:  128-255, so I shortened the statement to this:

```
SELECT description
FROM your_table
WHERE regexp_like (description, '['||chr(128)||'-'||chr(255)||']');
```

Short way to grab a range.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, it may perform better than 30+ single WHERE clause but it won't be much prettier:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM your_table 
 WHERE regexp_like(description, '['||chr(128)||chr(129)||...||chr(160)||']')
```